# Can't get multiple values from json using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Hello I'm kinda new to programming and I'm trying to use ajax and would like to get the value from this php, but can't get it to work

```
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];

$query = "SELECT * from ipcr where userID = '".$userID."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $current_id = $row['id'];
    $current_details = $row['details'];
    $current_dateCreated = $row['dateCreated'];
    $current_ipcrCode = $row['ipcrCode'];
    $current_employeeNumber = $row['employeeNumber'];

    $array = array(
        'id'=>$current_id,
        'details' => $current_details,
        'dateCreated' => $current_dateCreated,
        'ipcrCode' => $current_ipcrCode,
        'employeeNumber' => $current_employeeNumber
    );

    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

but i keep getting an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 173

and when i try to validate my json it gives
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dNSq.png)

This is the actual output that the php echoed.

```
{"id":"21836","details":"Details here","dateCreated":"2018-08-01 14:25:28","ipcrCode":"22703","employeeNumber":"140010663"}
{"id":"21837","details":"details here","dateCreated":"2018-08-01 14:25:57","ipcrCode":"22703","employeeNumber":"140010663"}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I use json_encode? it seems that the format I echoed is wrong.

also this is how my script looks like

```
function get_ipcr() {
    var userID = <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/php/load_ipcr.php",

        dataType: "json",
        success: function(results) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Your `echo json_encode($array);` is *inside* your whole loop so it is echoing multiple times. Move it after the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are echoing the JSON object in loop. This results in something like `{valid JSON}{valid JSON}` which isn't a valid JSON.

You can fix this by:

```
$employees = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $current_id = $row['id'];
    $current_details = $row['details'];
    $current_dateCreated = $row['dateCreated'];
    $current_ipcrCode = $row['ipcrCode'];
    $current_employeeNumber = $row['employeeNumber'];
// Record into employees array.
    $employees[] = array(
        'id'=>$current_id,
        'details' => $current_details,
        'dateCreated' => $current_dateCreated,
        'ipcrCode' => $current_ipcrCode,
        'employeeNumber' => $current_employeeNumber
    );
}
echo json_encode($employees);
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

There's several things you are going to hear about from different comments / answers, I recommend that you listen to them - it may seem overwhelming, or like "too much info" - but trust me, we are all here to help!

**The answer to your problem**
Bake the *entire* JSON string into a single array (an array of arrays), rather than echoing out the JSON string multiple times within the loop.

**Additional tip**
Also, as a tip, you are making more typing for yourself by assigning all the variable (`$current_id = $row['id']`, etc).  You can just use the `$row['id']` directly  ... below you can see that I've shown one way to streamline your code:

```
// shorthand version of $array = array()
$array = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // don't bother assigning $row values to a series of variables
    // removed all the lines like the next one....
    // $current_id = $row['id'];
    // push this record onto the array of arrays....
    $array[] = [
        // assign the array values directly from $row
        'id'             =>$row['id'],
        'details'        => $row['details'],
        'dateCreated'    => $row['dateCreated'],
        'ipcrCode'       => $row['ipcrCode'],
        'employeeNumber' => $row['employeeNumber']
    ];
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

**Lastly, and MOST IMPORTANT**
Please, please - do NOT write query statements like that.  It is wide open to SQL Injection attacks, which are a serious issue.

Please [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/870729) about how to [prevent SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/870729).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and all the tips!